# Excel - Find a value from a column of multiple values and return the value associated with the searched value

Tags: excel, find

I have seen this formula that is good to manually add values and return a value but is laborious to maintain:
`=IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hello",[@Column1])),"Welcome",(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hi",[@Column1]))),"Welcome",TRUE,"")`

But what I want is to make it easier to maintain, using a list of search terms and the expected text result in a table e.g.

- Search is ideally case insensitive
- Search will find the text anywhere in the searchable text cell

**Search and results criteria table**

| Search | Return |
| --- | --- |
| Cat | Yes |
| Human | No |
| Dog | Yes |
| Baby | No |

Text to search in and expected return value - will look for any value from the Search list table values and fill in the value from the Return list above e.g.

| Searchable text | Returns |
| --- | --- |
| Labrador dog | Yes |
| Australian Human | No |
| Labrador cat | Yes |
| Austrian baby | No |
| Labrador dog boy | Yes |

Sorry for the really crap example
Thanks
Dean

See above
`=IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hello",[@Column1])),"Welcome",(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hi",[@Column1]))),"Welcome",TRUE,"")`

Works but not ideal for large lists of search values and results

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula-

```
=IF(OR(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),$G$2:$G$5,$H$2:$H$5,"No")="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

To make it dynamic spill array, use `MAP()` or `BYROW()` function.

```
=MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(x,IF(OR(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(x,," "),$G$2:$G$5,$H$2:$H$5,"No")="Yes"),"Yes","No")))
```

[image]

> Edit: If you use `TRUE/FALSE` then we can simplify it like-

```
=OR(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),$G$2:$G$5,$H$2:$H$5,FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: you are a guru - I was able to amend below to my formatted table easily and it works perfectly - THANK YOU!

=IF(OR(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),$G$2:$G$5,$H$2:$H$5,"No")="Yes"),"Yes","No")

Comment: One more question, is there a way that if the lookup does not find a match e,g. a value in Column G is not found in Column A, that it leaves the Return field blank?